# My git branch is showing 'origin/master' and 'origin/HEAD' in Sourcetree and I don't know how to merge the two

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I recently merged a branch I was working on with the 'master' branch. I must have (still kind of a git n00b) done something when pushing or pulling that created both an `origin/master` and an `origin/HEAD` branches. Unfortunately, I didn't keep a record of what commands I ran that did this. Currently, my team has a bunch of code in their master copies that I'm not getting when I check out the project (even if I `clone` to a new location).

Here's a screenshot of what Sourcetree is showing:

[image: 2 branches]

I really need to get this resolved so I can keep working so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not something you need to worry about. I also have it in some of my repositories, but it's something like, just a pointer to `origin/master`. If you do `git branch -r`, you should see this.

Comment: Hmmm ... any ideas on why my master is so out of sync with the ones my teammates have?

Comment: Well of course, since you have different repositories, you need to bring them in sync. So, is your question actually "how to merge _your_ work with that of `origin`"?

Answer (score 16):

It is just a pointer to master, a symbolic link if you wish. You can safely delete it by doing the following in a terminal (or git bash/cygwin for windows users):

1. navigate to your repository
2. execute: `git remote set-head origin -d`

now it should be gone:

```
$ git branch -r
origin/master
```

Answer (score 8):

The branches you see that begin with `origin/` are so-called "remote-tracking braches".  They tell you the position of the branches in the repository `origin` the last time git fetched from that repository.

It's nothing to worry about - this is actually helpful information.  If you think those branch positions are out of date, you can run:

```
git fetch origin
```

... to update them.

In any repository, `HEAD` is special kind of ref (a "symref") that represents the current branch (or current commit, if you're not on a particular branch).

---

You can see in the diagram that your `master` branch is actually one commit ahead of `origin/master`, so if your colleagues have been pushing to `master` in `origin` and you ran `git fetch origin` (or something equivalent) recently, you already have all their work.  However, they will be missing out on your commit until you push that.

You say:

> Currently, my team has a bunch of code in their master copies that I'm not getting when I check out the project (even if I clone to a new location).

If that's the case, they're probably pushing to a different branch, a different repository, or they haven't pushed their work at all.

Comment: Also `git merge origin/<some_branch>` to merge `<some_branch>` with your currently checked out branch. That way, not only you update your copy of `origin`'s branches, but you actually get the changes in your local ones.

Comment: I didn't mention that because in the OP's situation merging `origin/master` won't do anything - his `master` is *ahead* of `origin/master`.

Comment: Yes, I just said it to make the answer more complete. Since he says "Currently, my team has a bunch of code in their master copies that I'm not getting when I check out the project", you told him to `git fetch`, I mentioned that following that, he should `git merge`.