# Why origin/head is in a different position than origin/master?

Tags: git, version-control, egit

As you can see from the picture below, in my remote repository origin/HEAD is not in the same position in history as origin/master. This is not intended so obviously I must have done something wrong.

In other questions such as this

[git doesn't seem to pull all updates - HEAD and origin/HEAD in different positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493055/git-doesnt-seem-to-pull-all-updates-head-and-origin-head-in-different-positio)

and this

[My git branch is showing 'origin/master' and 'origin/HEAD' in Sourcetree and I don't know how to merge the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527287/my-git-branch-is-showing-origin-master-and-origin-head-in-sourcetree-and-i-d)

people are saying in their answers that origin/HEAD is "not important".

However I'm not satisfied by this explanation. WHY is it not important?  What are the implications of my situation? How can I fix it (if there is anything to fix), maybe just by fetching from the remote as someone suggests in the linked answers?

Also, here [What is HEAD in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-git-head-exactly) the accepted answer cites a situation known as detached head; however in the documentation here http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head the case described is the opposite, where HEAD refers to a newer commit, compared to the one referenced by master. So I'm not sure that my situation can be described as detached head.

[image: origin/head is behind while origin/master is updated]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ORIG_HEAD does not indicate the HEAD of origin.

ORIG_HEAD marks the previous location of your HEAD, before an operation like rebase was performed. See more about it here: [HEAD and ORIG_HEAD in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git)

You can disable the visibility of ORIG_HEAD in the View Menu of History, disable 'Show->Additional Refs'

Comment: Wow. You just blew away my mind. That tag in the history window is not at all what I thought it was. Now I understand why I see it: I have done a rebase last night. Besides, I should have tagged the question with Egit, since this is specific to this software: I'll do it now. Thank you very much for clarifying everything.

Comment: `ORIG_HEAD` is not specific to EGit, Git also creates it before a rebase and other operations. It may just be that you never saw it because it is not shown when you do `git log` on the command line.